# Swift UIViewAnimation with spring moves to wrong place then jumps

Tags: ios, swift2, uiviewanimation, uianimation

I'm trying to animate a label moving to another place with a spring effect.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 1, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: { () -> Void in
    self.textLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y-220)
}, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
})
```

Basically it animates the label moving to a wrong place but after the animation finishes it suddenly jumps to the place I want it to go to.

What is causing this issue?

Comment: I slowed down the animations and it doesn't have this issue. I loaded the app onto my ios device and it also has this problem.

Comment: are you launching multiple animations at once?

Comment: Oh! That might be the problem, thank you for reminding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an animation inside another animation and it caused this issue. Now it is solved.